# Slurm Question: Array Job VS srun in a sbatch

Tags: slurm

What's the difference between the two following parallelization schemes on Slurm?

**Scheme 1**

Run `sbatch script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
## more options
srun echo hello
```

This summons 8 jobs that run `echo hello`

**Scheme 2**
I've accomplished something similar using array jobs.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=arrayJob
#SBATCH --output=arrayJob_%A_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=arrayJob_%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --array=1-8
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1

# Print this sub-job's task ID
echo hello
```

Is there any difference between the two schemes? They both seem to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scheme 1 is one single job (with 8 tasks) while Scheme 2 is 8 distinct jobs (each with one task). In the first case, all the tasks will be scheduled at the same time, while in the second case, the 8 tasks will be scheduled independently one of another.

With the job array (Scheme 2), if 8 CPUs become available at once, they will all start at the same time, but if only 4 CPUs become available at first, 4 tasks will run, the other 4 remaining pending. When the initial 4 are done, the other 4 are started. It is typically used in the case of [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) jobs, where the processes do not need to communicate or synchronise, like for applying the same program to a list of files.

By contrast, with a single job (Scheme 1), Slurm will start the 8 tasks at the same time, so it will need 8 CPUS to become available at the same time. This is typically only used with parallel jobs where processes need to communicate with each others, for instance using an [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) library.